# Unknown characters are being printed in Java

Tags: java, jsp, unicode

I am working on Java platform with IDE (jdeveloper). I am using simple text box in one jsp and sending its string to another jsp where I get that string and simply display that there, it works fine until the user puts some special character. When user puts special character the character is displayed as unknown character shown as ?. I understand the encoding issues, that's why UTF-8 is being used but still the problem is there.

Can anybody suggest me about it. I want to give freedom to the user to type anything in any language.

Comment: Try to post a real example, your jsp page, your code. A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will accept any character
The `pageEncoding` at the top will tell the server to decode the contents to UTF-8 and then send

In File.html

```
  <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <html>
  <form action="hello.jsp" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit name" />
```

In Hello.jsp file
Here `setCharacterEncoding` will encode the contents.

```
  <%
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    String name   = request.getParameter("name");
    Hello <%=name%><br>
  %>
```

This will echo the characters sent from the File.html
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but the output is â­ â¢ â¬ â, if I enter this ☭ ☢ € →.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is used.

Comment: This might help you : Euro Symbol in ASCII Code
ASCII Type Code
Decimal 8364
Hexadecimal 20AC
Alt-code: Alt + 0128
HTML Number &#8364;
HTML Name &euro;
Unicode U+20AC
ISO/IEC 8859-15 0164
Symbol €

Comment: The unicode for **€** is **U+20AC** since its not handled in UTF-8 u should transcode it to UTF-* first.

Comment: shall I use UTF-* ?

Comment: <p>Display &euro;</p>
This will display **€**

Comment: Check the main solution which i have edited.. let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks again for your prompt answer, but I dont know why my IDE is still showing ????????? as an output if I print those characters in command like System.out.println("‡§ª∏∑€™");. Please note that I am using Jdeveloper as an IDE.

Comment: If I print the output to a webpage, its working fine but when I use System.out.println("‡§ª∏∑€™"); it shows ??????????